# NsmutableArray setValue ObjectatIndex?

Tags: ios

I could't setvalue of selected index with nsmutablearray.There is my code:

```
[[retArray objectAtIndex:1] setValue:str forKey:@"name"];
```

this line give error. What is the error?

Comment: You tell us what the error is ;-). We don't know what kind of object `objectAtIndex:1` is.

Comment: yeah, what ***is*** the error?  Right now we're just guessing "`retArray`" is a NSArray object.

Comment: retarray is a nsmutablearray and str is a nsstring object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

correct code should be  is

```
[retArray insertObject:str atIndex:1];
```

or

```
[retArray addObject:str];
```

or if you are using a dictionary

```
[retArray insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:str forKey:@"name"] atIndex:1];
```

Comment: Last one is what i look for. thanks. how can i get it [retarray objectatindex:0]objectforkey@"name"] didnt work..

Comment: try the following     NSDictionary *dic = [retArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog([dic objectForKey:@"name"]);
also dont forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: please try [retarray objectatindex:1] objectforkey@"name"], and tell me if it worked :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12066/discussion-between-omar-abdelhafith-and-yatanadam)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should explicitly tell us what exact error it gives you then what you are doing in your code is:

- retrieving element at index `1`
- assuming that the item you got from the array is compliant to `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol (mostly a `NSMutableDictionary`)
- setting a field of the element retrieved

Code is correct as it is, the only concern could be that the array is not mutable (hence `NSArray` instead that `NSMutableArray`)

Answer (score 0):

you are using method of dictionary ...Refer [NSMutableArray Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)